# .htaccess redirect anything after

Tags: .htaccess

I have two domains, one old and one new. The structure on both of the sites is identical so what I need is to transfer anything after the domain to the new page

```
http://testurl.com/absolutely/anything/here
```

to

```
 http://testurl2.com/absolutely/anything/here
```

ive tried:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://testurl2.com/$1
```

but nothing is working :/

what every comes after the main url needs to be sent to the new domain.

Comment: Hi, please clarify your question. Both links looks identical to me. From and To. Also let me know, if its about transferring to *new domain* or *some other directory within same domain*

Comment: @Log1cツ hey I have done that, sorry it was a mistype

Comment: What is not working and what error are you getting?

Comment: just page not found - when I type in testurl.com/test/test it just fails. I need it to get anything after the url and add it to the new one.

Comment: Are these 2 domains on same server or different servers?

Comment: same server. I think i've fixed it. It was a caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^testurl.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.testurl.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://testurl2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

1. `[R=301]` flag is used to redirect URL by status 301
2. `[L]` flag is used to break rule matching for further rules if it matched given rule.